# Django static files not loading

Tags: django

I'm trying to add .css and .js file in my HTML template files that made for Django. I have followed the [official doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/), so my configurations set to:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
            (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                {'document_root': settings.STATIC_DOC_ROOT}),
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_DOC_ROOT = ''/myfirstapp/templates/seminar_form/'
```

But still I couldn't get it right, those .css .js and image files are still doesn't load in my HTML,but those files can access (perfectly viewable) from hitting the URL on browser
like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/images/calendar.png
```

Template code

```
<img src="{{ site_media }}images/calendar.png">
```

Comment: How do you link to them in the template? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can view the files by hitting the URL directly in your browser, then I'd guess you've got your [`MEDIA_URL`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url) settings wrong, or there's something wrong in your template code. What URL is your HTML referencing for your CSS/JS/Images?

Make sure you're passing through your `MEDIA_URL` so it's available in your template's context, which you do by wrapping up the request passed to your view functions in a `RequestContext`, like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Provided you've got your `MEDIA_URL` setting correct, and you are serving your media correctly (which your question suggests you are) you should be able to access media using things like:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}relative/path/to/media.jpg" alt="Foobar" />
```

#### After edit to show template code:

From your template code, it looks like you're trying to reference files rooted at a template variable called `site_media`, which probably doesn't exist.

You need to put something like this in your `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_URL = u'/site_media/'
```

Then change your template code to something like this:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/calendar.png">
```

and make sure you're passing `MEDIA_URL` to your template from your view function.

#### After comment asking for clarification about `RequestContext`:

The online Django book has some helpful (though currently lacking in some parts) [documentation](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter10/) about `RequestContext`. Personally, I use the [`render_to`](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home) decorator from django-annoying to avoid having to think about it. In place of my earlier sample view code, you can just do this:

```
from annoying import render_to

@render_to('my_template.html')
def some_view(request):
    ...
    return my_data_dictionary
```

Essentially, you just decorate your view function, passing in the template you want rendered, and then just return a `dict` containing the extra context variables you want set (i.e. context variables in addition to those that are set for you by `RequestContext`, such as `MEDIA_URL`).

This approach obviously doesn't work if your view might use different templates depending on some condition, but there are simple ways around that:

```
def some_view(request, some_var):
  ...
  if some_var:
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  else:
    return render_to_response('my_other_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
def some_view(request, some_var):
  ...
  if some_var:
    return _some_private_view(request, my_data_dictionary)
  else:
    return _some_other_private_view(request, my_data_dictionary)

@render_to('my_template.html')
def _some_private_view(request, my_data_dictionary):
  return my_data_dictionary

@render_to('my_other_template.html')
def _some_private_view(request, my_data_dictionary):
  return my_data_dictionary
```

Which seems clearer to me, at least.

Comment: I really didn't get what you have said, there's nothing mentioned about the MEDIA URL in that official doc, please could you explain more further.

Comment: @MMRUser - yes there is (I even linked to the docs for you when I first mentioned `MEDIA_URL`).

Comment: @MMRUser - I've edited my answer now you've posted your template code - there's a bit more help about this problem available at http://arthurkoziel.com/2008/09/02/handling-static-files-django/. If you've read that and are still stuck, add a comment explaining how and I'll try to help!

Comment: I made the configurations that you have mentioned,and it's working just fine thanks for your help.By the way If you can please explain more about Django template's RequestContext.

Answer (score 2):

simple explanation about image loading, I've found:

in settings.py:

```
from os import path

#media files are in <project folder>/static-media
MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)), 'static-media')
```

in urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns += patterns(
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )
```

usage in html:

```
<!--image location -  <project folder>/static-media/images/calendar.png-->
<img src="/media/images/calendar.png">
```

Comment: about MEDIA_ROOT: if in urlpatterns we write {'document_root': 'static-media'}, then there is no need to write code MEDIA_ROOT=path.join(... in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

What has worked for me is, adding the static files path to the STATICFILES_DIRS. IN development environment this seems a better solution.

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   '/path/to/your/static/files/',
 )
```

ex:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   '/home/chathuranga/App/templates/',
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: A great answer any way have to try this